# How to convert multiple rows into multiple columns with unique IDs without code IN MS EXCEL OR MS ACCESS

Tags: excel, ms-access

Data I have:

```
ID    IMAGE
--    ------
1     1.JPG
1     5.JPG
1     12.JPG
1     4.JPG
2     9.JPG
2     41.JPG
2     4.JPG
```

Required Result:

```
ID    IMAGE 1    IMAGE 2     IMAGE 3    IMAGE 4
--    -------    -------     -------    -------
1     1.JPG      5.JPG       12.JPG     4.JPG
2     9.JPG      41.JPG      4.JPG
```

Comment: What is a row, what is a column here? On what condition do you base the assignment to columns?

Comment: I need only one ID per row and different image urls on each respective ID row in different columns. please see the required result table above.

Comment: Do you know the maximum possible number of images for any given id? Or have a number that you know it will not exceed?

Comment: @fraggle Maximum 7 Images per unique ID/Row

Comment: Cheers, at work now, will sort out in around 8.5 hours. Sorry for delay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Formula I used in column C:

="IMAGE "&COUNTIF(A2:A8,A2)&"-"&A2

It is important that A2:A8 covers the full range of the data (doesn't matter if it is bigger than the data range). This basically creates a unique key for each image/ID pair that can be referenced in the table in F2:M3 (the note beneath the table erroneously states G2:M3 - typo on my part!) When you fill this down column C it will count all subsequent instance of the ID and alter the lookup key accordingly.

Column D just repeats the image name from your data in column B

I've created a named range that covers C1:D8 (this should cover the full length of the data columns that you have, define named range under 'Formulas' in Excel 2010 - select the range and give it a name I've called mine ID_IMAGE_LOOKUP.

I copied the ID column and used Excel's 'Remove Duplicates' feature from the Data tab to just leave unique IDs and then listed IMAGE 1...7 across the top row.

Now I'm ready to create a formula in cell F2 that references the unique ID column in E2:E3 and the image# number header row F1:L1 as follows:

=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(F$1&"-"&$E2,ID_IMAGE_LOOKUP,2,FALSE),"")

Note the $ signs to fix the column reference on E and row reference on 1, when I copy/paste/drag the formula to fill all of the boxes in the table the formula will always refer to the header row and ID column

I've assumed that you aren't fussed about what order the images are listed in as this will give a reverse list (see the first image for ID is 4.jpg). If this is a problem it would be a little more complicated but this approach could be adjusted to suit, something like take the current count for the ID away from the MAXIF() of the ID counts? Might need two count columns to avoid circular reference?

Comment if you get stuck/this doesn't make sense

Apologies for delay getting back to you, longer day than I'd anticipated!

Comment: Thank you so much! You have saved my hours of work. Thanks again and sorry for the delayed feedback. Thumbs UP!